# Irreducible operators

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, banach-lattices

I would like some reference to books that talk about irreducible operators on Banach lattices and its properties. A quick google search did not reap fruitful results.

**Edit 1:** I'm especially interested in properties of the adjoint of an irreducible operator.

**Edit 2:** This question has now been asked [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294005/reference-request-irreducible-operators?noredirect=1#comment729747_294005)